# Python udp sockets in windows (can't send msg to server if ran it in command promt(in IDE send's fine) )

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a ploblem with socket communication in my python app. I'm using python32. OS windows 7.
In my task i must use UDP sockets. If i ran my app from IDE(Eclipse) communication between client and server is fine.

BUT: 
if i ran my app in Command Promtp and then i can't to communicate from client to server (get errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed).  On windows xp app work fine.
I'm trying to turn off firewall but it doesn't help.
Why i can't communicate from cmd?

Client connection:

```
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.settimeout(15)
except socket.error as msg:
    print(msg)
    s.close()
    s = None

addr=(HOST,int(PORT))
msg="CONNECT"
s.sendto(bytes(msg,"ascii"),addr)
try:
    data = s.recvfrom(1024)[0]
except socket.timeout as err:
    print("Connection lost! /cry")
    sys.exit(1)
```

and server code:

```
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error as msg:
    print(msg)
    s = None

s.settimeout(45)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',PORT))

if s is None:
    print('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)
print("Server created. Waiting for player.")
sost = "Server"
while True:
    try:
        (data,addr) = s.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout as err:
        print("Nobody want's to connect! /cry")
        sys.exit(1)

    if data == b"CONNECT":
        print("User from {0} connected".format(addr))
        s.sendto(b"CONNECT_OK",addr)
    break;
```

PS: Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

can you print out the value of the addr variable when you get the exception? maybe something silly with the address (embedded line feed or something like that)

Probably safest to add a addr.strip() call?

Comment: Thank you! I can't imagine that problem is with it because in XP and in Debugger work's fine. ADDR consist of ('10.20.213.5\r', 43212). But why "\r" added?

Comment: Are you getting this address from user input? Line endings can be troublesome sometimes...

Comment: how do you get the value of HOST?